# Memory leak with IO.RecyclableMemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I took a dump from my API and found that RecyclableMemoryStream has by far largest size, together with FileBufferingReadStream. I have middleware that logs each request/response, and I suspect that there is an issue, however, this doesn't happen on other APIs, that has the same middleware.

I couldn't find any issue, and cannot reproduce this when APIs is running on my machine, also I don't see anything unusual with the code, but besides this middleware, I am not using streams in the rest of the code.

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
        private const string CorrelationIdHeaderKey = "X-Correlation-ID";
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            RecyclableMemoryStreamManager recyclableMemoryStreamManager)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoggingMiddleware>();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                return;
            }

            var skippable = new[] { HttpMethods.Connect, HttpMethods.Options, HttpMethods.Trace };
            if (skippable.Any(x => x.Equals(context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue &&
                context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("swagger"))
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            string correlationId = null;
            if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(CorrelationIdHeaderKey, out StringValues correlationIds))
            {
                correlationId = correlationIds.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Equals(CorrelationIdHeaderKey));
            }
            else
            {
                correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                context.Request.Headers.Add(CorrelationIdHeaderKey, correlationId);
            }
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                if (!context.Response.Headers.
                TryGetValue(CorrelationIdHeaderKey, out correlationIds))
                    context.Response.Headers.Add(CorrelationIdHeaderKey, correlationId);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            await LogRequest(context);
            await LogResponse(context);
        }

        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            using (var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
            {
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);

                var queryString = context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? $"?{context.Request.QueryString.Value}" : "";
                _logger.LogInformation($">> {context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}{context.Request.Path}{queryString} headers: {string.Join("; ", context.Request.Headers.Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}"))} Body: {ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}");
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            }
        }
        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
            using (var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
            {

                context.Response.Body = responseBody;
                await _next(context);
                context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var queryString = context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? $"?{context.Request.QueryString.Value}" : "";
                var message = $"<< {context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}{context.Request.Path}{queryString} {context.Response.StatusCode} X-Correlation-ID: {context.Request.Headers["X-Correlation-ID"]} headers: {string.Join("; ", context.Response.Headers.Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}"))} Body: {text}";

                if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 500) 
                    _logger.LogError(message);
                else if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 400) 
                    _logger.LogWarning(message);
                else
                    _logger.LogInformation(message);

                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }

        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
                    int readChunkLength;
                    do
                    {
                        readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk,
                                                           0,
                                                           readChunkBufferLength);
                        textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
                    } while (readChunkLength > 0);
                    var body = textWriter.ToString();

                    return body;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your observed size within the recycleable stream pool size?

Comment: How can I know that? I didn't define anything regarding the pool size

Comment: `RecyclableMemoryStreamManager`'s `MaximumFreeSmallPoolBytes` and `MaximumFreeLargePoolBytes`. From [the docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream): "If you set these to 0, you can have unbounded pool growth, which is essentially indistinguishable from a memory leak."

Comment: I didn't set any of the mentioned. I guess defaults are 0

Comment: @StephenCleary that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting this comment to a proper answer:

`RecyclableMemoryStreamManager`'s `MaximumFreeSmallPoolBytes` and `MaximumFreeLargePoolBytes` determine how many bytes are kept in the recyclable pool. From the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream): "If you set these to 0, you can have unbounded pool growth, which is essentially indistinguishable from a memory leak."

Also, [the default size is 0](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream/blob/8356bf5bfb79c91a4ddd3c3f3afc51b952e5fff2/docs/Microsoft.IO/RecyclableMemoryStreamManager/MaximumFreeSmallPoolBytes.md) ([for both](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream/blob/8356bf5bfb79c91a4ddd3c3f3afc51b952e5fff2/docs/Microsoft.IO/RecyclableMemoryStreamManager/MaximumFreeLargePoolBytes.md)), so really the docs mean to say: "*unless* you set these to something *other* than 0, you will have unbounded pool growth, which is essentially indistinguishable from a memory leak".

> this doesn't happen on other APIs, that has the same middleware... cannot reproduce this when APIs is running on my machine

Most likely, the misbehaving API had much larger (and/or much more concurrent) requests than other APIs (or local testing), and so its recycle pool is much larger as a result.